# BIRT Report - using Library as basis for report design files, adding new Report Parameter not reflected in all report design files

Tags: eclipse, parameters, birt

BIRT Report - using Library as basis for report design files, adding new Report Parameter not reflected in all report design files.

I designed several report parameters into my library file and created 40+ report designs from it.  Now I'm adding a couple new report parameters to the Library file that I'd like to see in all of my Birt Reports.   If I open a report design file, Eclipse signals me that the library changed if I modify something on the Master Page, but not when I add a new Report parameter to the library file.   Is this a defect or do I have to got to each and every report and add the new report parameters manually?

I saw that for individual Report parameters while editing the report design, there is a button in the Properties (bottom window) to "Restore Properties from the original library item", if it were manually overridden in the report, but nothing to reflect additional parameters.
Here is my library outline showing my parameters missing from the report; followed by what my report reflects.
[Library Report parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9oky.png)
[Design shows missing Report parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhp5k.png)

Answer (score 0):

...  Is this a defect or do I have to got to each and every report and add the new report parameters manually?

This is intended.
You'll have to add each parameter manually.

A BIRT library is a collection of items like layout items, data sets, data sources, report parameters etc.
A BIRT report is more or less the same, the difference being that a report has a body.
Individual items in the report can reference library items.

But there is no such thing like an "item group" - which you would need.

But if you have a lot of reports and a lot of new parameters, you can use the BIRT design engine API (DE API) to open the reports and add the parameters programmatically. Since examples for using the DE API are rare, doing it manually will probably be faster than creating a program for this. Aapprox. 3min x 40 reports = 2h for doing it manually, developing a program will take you at least twice as long, but could be useful in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.  This is unfortunate but understood and how I've been doing it for this specific type of change up until now.